# What is this set with tan plates and dark red and dark tan tiles?

Tags: set-identification

What set does this belong to?  The two top tan plates slide out.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it includes only parts from Ninjago set [2507 Fire Temple](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2507-1), however it appears to have been changed around a bit.
[image]

Comment: One can see the temple splitting in half, and the base halves sliding out, in the images at https://rebrickable.com/sets/2507-1/fire-temple/